# remove toolbar from navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

I have a navigation controller where I add a toolbar based on user input.

When the user hits back to the home screen. I don't want the toolbar.

```
self.navigationcontroller.toolbar.hidden = YES;
```

This just hides the toolbar and the UIImage on the homepage is now shifted up the 40px and the black background appears where the toolbar is hidden.

How can I REMOVE the toolbar so the image doesn't get pushed up.

Comment: Are you using autolayout? Doing [self.navigationController setToolBarHidden:YES animated:YES] in the `viewWillAppear` of your home screen view controller should do the trick.

Comment: You might have to adjust the constraints on the image view to pin to top and bottom of the super view

Comment: I am using autolayout. the image bottom is bound to the superview.  But if I don't remove the toolbar in that superview, the image gets shifted up the 40 or so points

Comment: @Dan Fairaizl from my posted answer below, the toolbarHidden was the correct way..not toolbar.hidden

Comment: if you post answer i'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.hidden = YES;
```

needed to be replaced with...

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the position of the child VC's `frame` move it with 40px down (animation with duration 0.25 f.e.), when you hide the toolbar, or change the navigation controllers `bounds` origin with `origin.y`+40, just like you would do, when you are hiding the status bar. But i think an empty space will remain, you should do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

For swift you need to write:

```
        self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
```